# What's the difference between saddle and inflection point?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

As far as I know, [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is a point where the concavity of the function changes. These points can be found by taking the second derivative and check if it is 0 and see whether the concavity actually changes on the either sides of the point.

I saw a video which states that saddle point is essentially the same thing but it applies to functions having two or more input variables.
But in this link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaddlePoint.html, they have found saddle points of a single variable function.

I am confused between both of these.

Comment: I'm not sure the Wolfram definition for saddle point is standard.  It's not even really consistent--compare its definition in 1-d to 2-d.

Comment: This site has a clear diagram: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-stationary-points-and-critical-points

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Saddle Point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaddlePoint.html):

> A point of a function or surface which is a stationary point but not an extremum.

[Inflection Point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html):

> An inflection point is a point on a curve at which the sign of the curvature (i.e., the concavity) changes.

An inflection point does not have to be a stationary point, but if it is, then it would also be a saddle point.

For a sufficiently differentiable function, a point is a saddle point if the smallest non-zero derivative is greater than $1$ and of odd order ([extremum test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtremumTest.html)).

For a twice differentiable function, a point is an inflection point if the second derivative changes sign around the point. A difference here is that the first derivative can be non-zero.

For example, for the function $f(x)=x^3+x$, $0$ is an inflection point but not a saddle point.

I resort to pathological examples such as $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac1x\right) & x\ne0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$ for a saddle point that is not an inflection point, since for elementary functions, [a saddle point is an inflection point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StationaryPoint.html).

Comment: Can inflection point be relative Maxima or minima ? @Kenny Lau

Comment: [Inflection points \[...\] are not local maxima or local minima](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) since the curve would be convex around a local minimum and concave around a local maximum.

Comment: I assumed the function to be twice differentiable.

Comment: Re: the final sentence: The point $(0,3)$ of the elementary function $f(x)=3$ is a saddle, but not inflection, point.

Answer (score -1):

> In mathematics, a saddle point or minimax point is a point on the
> surface of the graph of a function where the slopes (derivatives) in
> orthogonal directions are all zero (a critical point), but which is
> not a local extremum of the function. - [Wikipedia: Saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)

- For functions with one variable a "stationary point that is not extremal" (extremal means either a minimum or a maximum) is a point where the function's first derivatives become zero and the second derivative changes sign.
- A saddle point is named after a horse saddle. So its visualizations are usually depicted as 3D with functions with two variables.
- Definition of a saddle point for functions with at least two variables is a point where the function has a zero derivative (or partial derivatives) and the function has different signs of curvature in different directions.

An example of a function with one variable that has an inflexion point which is also stationary (You may call it saddle point although the shape of it is a diagonal 2D projection of a 3D horse saddle.) is: $$f(x) = x^n, \quad n \in \mathbb{O}$$
For example, for the function $f(x) = x^3$, the point $x = 0$ is a saddle point because $f’(x) = 0$ but $f(x)$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).